# Add image path and a button in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, button, arraylist

I want to add image path in an array and also add a button. How can I do that?

```
function prac_createTable(){

var table = document.createElement('table');
table.setAttribute('id', 'empTable');

var arrValue = new Array()
arrValue.push(['The alchemist', '**path of the image from local**', '**button**'])
```

}

Comment: [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) is a function so you'll have to call it with the arguments (you're missing the parenthesis):
`arrValue.push(['The alchemist', '**path of the image from local**', '**button**'])`

Comment: Okay. And what about image path?